# system gets stuck in keyboard mode

Tags: windows-7

Not sure how to explain this but sometimes I will be working, usually with a bunch of windows open (RDP, VMs, etc) and then I'll switch back to a web browser or notepad and I'll start typing. The system acts as if I'm pressing key combinations while holding the windows key. For example, if I press 'E' the my computer window will open. If I press 'Space' then all windows will go transparent. It's as if the windows key is stuck on (of course the physical key is NOT stuck in any way so cleaning the keyboard isn't a solution).

This happens on all of my systems as one point or another. (WinXP, Vista and Win7)

- why does this happen?
- how do you fix it without rebooting?

Comment: Both the keyboard and the mouse switching have 2 States, the down state and the up state.  I have seen instances where the system saw it in the wrong state.  any keyboard tool that shows both states would show that.  Could a 3rd party hotkey thing have sent out a down state and not an up state ? http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=key%20up%20key%20down%20jquery&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=fe49d561ad75bea3&biw=1527&bih=780&pf=p&pdl=500

Comment: That is possible, when it happens again i'll try to see if thats the case using a visual keyboard. I don't have any hotkey tools installed. It is possible that one of the apps i'm using does that. I'm leaning toward the VM or RDP. Usually only happens when i'm running one of those.

Comment: this happens to me too. My toddler slams on my keyboard and it gets stuck in some weird mode, seems like CTRL or ALT is depressed and I can't type anything but international characters. End up having to restart. So annoying! Anyone knows how to fix without restarting? 